# Fill a pseudo- table() with values from another column

Tags: r

How can I pseudo-`table()` two variables but fill with values from third column/ separate list?

Example:

```
library(ggplot2) # diamonds data
data(diamonds)
T.matrix <- with(diamonds, table(color, clarity))
```

Produces:

```
     clarity
color   I1  SI2  SI1  VS2  VS1 VVS2 VVS1   IF
    D   42 1370 2083 1697  705  553  252   73
    E  102 1713 2426 2470 1281  991  656  158
    F  143 1609 2131 2201 1364  975  734  385
    G  150 1548 1976 2347 2148 1443  999  681
    H  162 1563 2275 1643 1169  608  585  299
    I   92  912 1424 1169  962  365  355  143
    J   50  479  750  731  542  131   74   51
```

I want a similar table with color by clarity except with fill = `reference$value` instead of `table()`'s count

```
reference <- expand.grid(clarity = c("I1", "SI2", "SI1", "VS2", "VS1","VVS2", "VVS1", "IF"),
                         color = c("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"))
reference$value <- 1:56
```

So: [D,I1] would have a value of 1, [SI1, D] = 2, [VS2, H] = 36, etc.

Comment: @jeremycg could you suggest another function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `tapply`:

```
tapply(diamonds$price, list(diamonds$color, diamonds$clarity), mean)
```

tapply takes your desired variable, groups it by the list of variables to group by, then applies the last function. The table output is maybe not so useful, depending on your desired use.

If you want your data in a more usable format, you might want to use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

diamonds %>% group_by(clarity, color) %>%
             summarise(mean(price))
```

Edit: It is the same!

```
tapply(reference$value, list(reference$color, reference$clarity), FUN = sum)
```

you need the fun or tapply collapses the output

Comment: Great solution! Maybe you want to use the transposed form of your result by putting your line of code as the argument of `t()` in order to obtain the same arrangement of columns and rows as in the OP.